Printing From A Split Container
I have a split container with a label that changes text to print. It triggers the printer I want just fine, the paper gets processed. However, there is nothing on the paper when I go to pick it up. My guess is that I am not telling it properly what to print. I have to print the label in the split container itself and not just the text because the positioning of the label gets factored into how the final product looks. I need the printer to see the positioning of the label relative to client area of the container.
Here is the code I am using for the printing:
Private Sub cmdPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdPrint.Click
    PrintDocument1.Print()
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(1, 1)
    Me.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(SplitContainer1.ClientRectangle.Left, SplitContainer1.ClientRectangle.Top, SplitContainer1.ClientRectangle.Width, SplitContainer1.ClientRectangle.Height))

    PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = cboPrinter.Text
End Sub


Dim bmp As New Bitmap(1, 1)?? <- SplitContainer1.ClientRectangle is already a Rectangle. You could make good use of these dimensions... -- Setting the PrinterName in PrintPage? You have probably done that already, somewhere else

Am I allowed to just print the client rectangle directly? I thought you had to set it to a bitmap or print document for it to be seen? I am new to VB.Net's way of printing. In VB6 you only had to say the object you wanted to print. VB.Net allows you a lot more control it seems.

Nope, you're not allowed to create a Bitmap with the size of 1 pixel x 1pixel to contain the much larger image generate by [Control].DrawToBitmap(). You can use the size of the Control you want to print to size the Bitmap. BTW, Me here is not the SplitContainer, it's the window (the Parent Form) -- BTW2, you're not actually printing anything. You have to use the Graphics object provided by PrintPageEventArgs to draw an Image (e.Graphics.DrawImage())

I was able to get it working using the following code. Thanks!
`Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(SplitContainer1.Panel1.Width, SplitContainer1.Panel1.Height)

SplitContainer1.Panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, SplitContainer1.Panel1.ClientRectangle)
e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0)

End Sub`
